# Z-index with fixed positon

Tags: html, css, z-index

I want to have my classes always in the front of the page, but it does not work.

Please help me to find a solution.

```css
.test {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 40px;
  top: 50% !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  float: right;
  position: fixed !important;
  transition: width 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.test .right {
  float: right;
  background: #4A90E2;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: middle;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.test .left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" style="background-color: #4A90E2;">
  <div class="right">
    <h6 style="transform:rotate(-90deg); color: white; margin-top:50px; margin-right:10px">
      <i style="color:white; " class="fa fa-phone fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Service
    </h6>
  </div>
  <div style="color:white;" class="left">
    <h3 style="color:white !important;"> Text</h3>
    <p style="margin-top:-20px;">sometext </p>
  </div>
</div>=
```

Comment: which class or classes? please specify.

Comment: and what is not working ?

Comment: The z-index doesn`t work. My class "test" with child-classes ".right and .left" are still behind other elements of my page.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index will not work because class right div is inside of test div. If you take class right div out of test div it will work.